# The axiom of regularity and "every element is also a set" [ZFC]

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Disclaimer: Yes I know, this question has been asked multiple times before here, and if you want, you can flag this question as duplicate. I only chose to make a new question because of the kind of backwards comment-reputation system.

We all know that the Axiom of Regularity states:

> For every non-empty set X, there exists an element y in X, so that X and y are disjoint.

and that Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (with the Axiom of choice, hence ZFC) doesn't need urelements to exist, thus every element is also a set. But that poses two questions for me:

1. For a set that doesn't have the empty set as an element, how does this work? 
   For example:

   > X = {1,2,3}, every element in X is also a set, so y can be {1}, {2} or {3}, but all of these are not disjunct with X, so what *is* disjoint with x? I know that every set *contains* the empty set as a subset, but "containing" and "element of" are not equal statements, or did I understand something wrong?

and if that works somehow:

2. Take the Power Set of that X, remove the empty set and repeat the procedure. Since every subset of X is included, again, how does it work? I'm confused.

   > X ={1,2}, so P(X) = {{},{1},{2},{1,2}} and P(X)/{} = {{1},{2},{1,2}}.

And just to clarify, I don't want anybody to tell me if that axiom is "not useful". I don't care. I'm here to learn about set theory, not to learn if it's worth it. Sorry, but I've seen that under the other questions too and it's just such a dodgy answer.

Comment: If it is indeed a duplicate you should look for the duplicate instead and specifically ask at which point do you not understand in the duplicate question/answer.

Comment: In your first example, $1$ is an element of $X$, not $\{1\}$. So for instance $1\cap X = \emptyset$. Of course, you probably need to define what you mean by $1$ first.

Comment: @user202729 Oh. Damn. Yes, that is an option too. *sigh* I really need to learn to use this forum better. Thanks. My thought, by the way, was, that I just didn't get attention in the places I wanted. But I haven't tried commenting on other questions yet.

Comment: $y\in x$ , not $y\subset x.$ If $x=\{1,2,3\}$ then no matter how you define $1,2, 3$ the axiom of Regularity (a.k.a. Foundation) implies $(1\cap x=\phi) \lor (2\cap x)=\phi \lor (3\cap x=\phi).$...... In particular $1\cap x=\phi$ means $\forall y \in 1\; (y\ne 1 \land y\ne 2\land y\ne 3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$ and $2$ and $3$ are sets, but since you are thinking about them in an abstract capacity of "three natural numbers" or even just "three distinct objects", there is no reason to treat them as one set or another. These could be the standard ordinal-based construction of $\Bbb N$; or you can use the fact that there is a canonical copy of $\Bbb N$ in any construction of $\Bbb R$, and maybe you meant these. And so on and so forth.

But in any case, let's take the standard ordinal based approach. So $0=\varnothing, 1=\{0\}, 2=\{0,1\}$ and $3=\{0,1,2\}$. In that case it is not hard to check that $1\cap\{1,2,3\}=\varnothing$. So indeed $1$ is the element guarnateed by the axiom of regularity. If you choose a different coding, then the answer could be different. So your mileage may vary when it comes to this answer.

With the power set example this is also not hard. Since $\{1\}$ is disjoint from $\mathcal P(X)$, as there is no element of $\mathcal P(X)$ which is the set $1$. Mainly because $1\neq\{1\}$. And again, your mileage may vary depending on your coding, but I'm assuming the standard coding as above. But any other coding schema will have an answer as one of these sets if not more.

Comment: Yes, I see my error now. I've assumed that 1, 2 and 3 are objects, but ZFC makes sure that these aren't needed (and thus they are also defined as sets of sets and sets again and so on). What happens, if every one of the sets 1,2 and 3 contains sets also included in X? Wait, what? Doesn't that imply that some kind of "recursion" and thus set containing itself occurs? Did I just answer my own question? Mind = Blown.

Comment: Regularity ensures that it is impossible that $1,2$ and $3$ all have non-empty intersection with $\{1,2,3\}$. That's exactly the point. The key issue here is that well-founded structures are exactly those where we can use recursion to define things, and the axiom of regularity ensures that $\in$ is well-founded and therefore *very* suitable for recursive definitions. (Of course, we also need the axiom of replacement when doing these recursive definitions in general, but that's another story.)

Comment: I suspected that. Thousand thanks to you.

Comment: Sorry, it's me again. I just wrote down what I understood and I found a (kind of) inconsistency: If I break down the standard construction of 1 into {0}, the intersection between it and {1,2,3} is empty. _But_ if I break it down even further into the absolute clusterf of empty sets, it doesn't work anymore. It makes sense, but that last one messes with my head.

Comment: You need to do this carefully, and yes, this will mess with your head at first. But you get used to these sort of things. The important thing is to do it carefully, one step at a time. And then the whole "mess of empty sets" makes more sense. Just remember, again, that $\{\varnothing\}\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: I was just about to write a comment when the ultimate insight came to me (again) that you only take the _contents_ when working with an intersection (how trivial), thanks to your comment (that the set of the empty set isn't equal to the empty set). Dude, you're awesome!